# scroll bottom of the div with jquery slim scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slimscroll

I am trying to scroll bottom when an ajax page is loading,I have used jquery slim scroll for scroll bar.

I have used this code in ajax.php page,so that when the page will be loaded,it will scroll directly to the bottom

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".chatScroll").scrollTop() }, 1000);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var body = $('body');
    body.animate({ scrollTop: body.height() }, 1000);
});
```